# Returning error intentionally at Controller method NOT WORKING

Tags: php, laravel, try-catch, laravel-10

I'm working with Laravel v10 and I wanted to test how the storing errors work with `try..catch` so I tried out this code:

```
public function updateDetails(ProfileDetailsUpdateRequest $request)
    {
        try {
            throw new \Exception('An error occurred!');

            $inputData = $request->all();
            $wholeData = array_intersect_key($inputData, array_flip(Member::getTableColumns()));
            Member::where('mbr_usr_id', Auth::user()->id)->update($wholeData);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
            $errorDetails = [
                'page' => Route::current()->uri(),
                'method' => Route::current()->methods(),
                'user_id' => optional(Auth::user())->id,
                'ip_address' => $request->ip(),
                'user_agent' => $request->userAgent(),
                'referrer' => $request->header('referer'),
                'request_data' => $request->all(),
                'stack_trace' => $e->getTraceAsString(),
            ];

            Log::channel('database')->error($errorMessage, $errorDetails);
        }
    }
```

So because I `throw new error exception`, the catch block should run and store the log of error but it does not work and not catching the error.

Instead the data gets updated like before.

So how can I throw and all an error from this method to test the catch block?

Comment: Are you sure it comes inside try block? We can't reproduce this at our end.

Comment: The code looks valid, you are throwing an error inside a `try` block, and the `catch` has the same exception, so it is literally going to work. Your issue could be, as @nice_dev stated, that you are never going inside the controller. Try removing the FormRequest you have in there, and just replace it with `Request`. Show us what you are getting back if it succeeds or not, but show us what you get back